# How to tell JSDoc that I'm passing a namespace object as parameter?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, documentation, jsdoc

I'm using an anonymous function to add methods to a namespace object. In the end, I would want JSDoc (version 3.3) to generate documentation for `MyNamespace.func1()`, `MyNamespace.func2()`, etc. I guess I could add this information to each of the methods defined in the function, but it would be a lot easier to have JSDoc3 recognize that `ns` is the same as `MyNamespace`. How do I do that?

```
/** @namespace */
var MyNamespace = {};

// (... some code that adds to MyNamespace ...)

(function (ns) {

    /** Method description 1 */
    ns.func1 = function (val) {};

    /** Method description 2 */
    ns.func2 = function (val) {};

    // ...etc

})(MyNamespace);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of a similar scenario in the JSDoc documentation for **[aliases](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html)**, see the section "Using @alias for static members of a namespace"

Comment: Thanks, I've that example. This could only work if I had a `var` declaration for a container somewhere inside the anon function, instead of a function argument. In the end, I gave in and restructured my code. IMHO, a documentation tool shouldn't force me to do that, but that's life. I'll add an answer for what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not possible with JSDoc 3 (yet).

I ended up using a merge/extend/augment-type helper function, like this:

```
(function (ns) {

    extend(ns, /** @lends ns */ {

        /** Method description 1 */
        func1: function (val) {},

        /** Method description 2 */
        func2: function (val) {},

        // ...etc
    });

})(MyNamespace);
```

This gives JSDoc everything it needs to create the proper documentation. One minor disadvantage is that `func1` will now show up as `extend.func1` in the Chrome error console stack trace.